# Node js windows child process on exit and close event

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack, node-webkit

Hi i am trying to invoke an event on closing of calculator.exe application,but the event itself raising while launching the application.. any help ?

```
var filePath="calc.exe";
var bat = exec(filePath);
bat.on('exit', function() {
 alert("exit");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "exit" with "SIGINT" instead:

```
bat.on('SIGINT', function() {
 alert("exit");
});
```